# Definition of convexity

Tags: convex-analysis

We know that a function is convex if we have $$\lambda f(x_1) + (1-\lambda)f(x_2) \ge f(\lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda)x_2)$$
where $0\le\lambda\le1$

But I don't know where is it come from ? Unfortunately , I can't understand it. I searched in the internet many times but it didn't help to me. If someone explain this expression is helpful.

Comment: Perhaps the Answer posted by C. Falcon will help.  Saying a function of one variable is *convex* essentially amounts to saying the region *above* the graph of the function is convex.  Sometimes we say the graph is "concave up" rather than calling the function convex, but the notions are equivalent.

Comment: Okay , but I have still problem . What is the meaning of "set of barycentric combinations of $A$ and $B$ "?

Comment: A different definition is that a function is convex iff its epigraph is convex. This is a visually intuitive definition, and it explains why we use the same word "convex" for both sets and functions.

Comment: @hardmath A [convex curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_curve) is commonly defined as one that stays on the same side of any of its tangents. In this sense, both graphs $y=x^2$ and $y=-x^2$ are convex curves, even though the former is defined by a [convex function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function) while the latter by a concave function. The geometrical definition of a convex function is that the set of points *above* its graph $y \ge f(x)$ (a.k.a. its [epigraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epigraph_(mathematics))) is convex .

Comment: @S.H.W If you look at the very first picture on the wikipedia page for [convex functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function) you'll see what the inequality means geometrically (except they use $t$ instead of $\lambda$).

Comment: @dxiv Yes , you're right. I read it but I'm really confuse about notions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The given inequality means that whenever you take two points on the graph of $f$, then the segment joining them is above the graph itself.

[image]

---

**Edit.** For the proof, it suffices to notice that for all $A,B\in\mathbb{R}^2$, one has: 
$$[AB]=\{(1-t)A+tB;t\in[0,1]\}.$$
This is essentially the definition of $[AB]$, which is the set of barycentric combinations of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: I know it , but can you show it mathematically ?

Comment: Are you familiar with parametrizing line segments starting from a point $a$ to a point $b$?

Comment: @Andrew Whelan Is your purpose slope of it ?

Comment: @C. Falcon Can you explain "set of barycentric combinations of $A$ and $B$ "?

Comment: @S.H.W A barycentric combination of points is a finite linear combination of points whose weights are positive and sum up to $1$. Intuitively, if $A$ has weight $\lambda\geqslant 0$ and $B$ weight $\mu\geqslant 0$, with $\lambda+\mu=1$, then the barycenter of the system $\{(A,\lambda),(B,\mu)\}$ is its center of mass. When I say that $[AB]$ is the set of barycentric combinations of $A$ and $B$, I mean that any point in $[AB]$ is given as the center of mass of such a system. For example, $A$ is the barycentric combination of $A$ with weight $1$ and $B$ with weight $0$.

Comment: @C. Falcon I know center of mass in physics but it seems that notion here is different from physics . Am I right ?

Comment: @S.H.W This is really the same thing. Perhaps in Physics you were taught that the center of mass of $(A,m_A)$ and $(B,m_B)$ is the unique point $G$ such that: $$m_A\overrightarrow{GA}+m_B\overrightarrow{GB}=\overrightarrow{0}.$$
Can you see the analogy with $(1-t)A+tB$?

Comment: Yes , but I'm not familiar with Barycentric Coordinates . Can you provide a resource for it ?

Comment: @S.H.W All the references I am familiar with are in French, however I believe the translation of *Géométrie* by M. Berger would be fine. See chapter $3$, part $4$ of the volume $1$.

Comment: Okay , Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

*Copied from my answer to the question [What is the intuition behind the mathematical definition of convexity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3010856/what-is-the-intuition-behind-mathematical-definition-of-convexity/3011489#3011489); that is essentially a duplicate, so I have just flagged it as such.*

The idea of convexity is is applicable in the first place to *shapes* or their *surfaces* and means ***bulging with no dents***. This concept can be applied when the shape is a set of points in a space for which we can define a “dent”; Euclidean spaces will do. It can also apply to part of the surface with no dents.

We can think of a *dent* as a place where you can draw a straight line segment joining two points in the set but leaving the set somewhere along that segment. If the set is “well-behaved” and has a surface, such a segment leaves the set at some point and re-enters it another, there is a subsegment joining points on the surface. In this case, we may define *convex* by saying *all points on such segments lie in the set*.

Derived from that, a function is described as convex when the set of points above (or maybe below) of its graph is convex. Note that a function may be [convex upwards or downwards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function), with the unqualified form meaning “convex downwards”. Further, as in your case, we call a function convex on an interval if the set of points above the graph with $x$ in that interval is convex.

The formulation with $λ$ and $1-λ$ formalises the above definition for the case of a function, that *all points on a segment between points on the graph lie in the set*: one side gives the value of the function $λ$ of the way along $[x_1,x_2]$, the other, the point that far along the segment joining two points on the line; the inequality says the point on the segment is above the graph, i.e. in the set.